# Creating .exe that needs no DLLs or Libraries

Tags: c, dll, compilation, linker

I currently have a project which requires the use of pthreads. On my own computer, I have pthread-win32 setup, and can compile the project as follows, and have it work fine.

```
gcc -o3 Engine.c -o Engine.exe -lpthread
```

The problem is, I want to be able to send this .exe to someone else who does not have gcc, and who does not have pthreads. I tried sending it to another computer of mine, and was unable to run it, throwing an error message about lpthreads not being installed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Link *statically* instead? It will make the executable file larger (maybe even *much* larger) but it will be more self-contained.

Comment: That sounds like what I am looking for. How would I go about linking it statically?

Answer (score -1):

This may ultimately generate a **gigantic** `.exe`, but anyway, use static linking...

```
gcc -O3 Engine.c -o Engine.exe -Wl,-Bstatic -lpthread
```

*Note*: That strange `-Wl,-Bstatic` is necessary *and* is correctly typed (it's an argument to the linker).

You need to specify `-Wl,-Bstatic` before any `-lmystaticlibrary` that may specify a library that you want to be statically-linked. If want other libraries to be dynamically-linked, pass `-Wl,-Bdynamic` *after* the static libraries.

Docs (**long and boring**) [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: While i was able to use that, and run it on my own machine, i still get a "pthread.dll" is missing error on my other computer.

Comment: @AndrewGrant: Do you have any kind of `pthread.lib` near you? Probably, the compiler is unable to find it, and you should give it to it explicitly, which results in the dynamic library (`.dll`) being used by default.

Comment: I think you are right about that being the issue. How should i resolve this? I followed the instructions found here. http://www.ipd.uni-karlsruhe.de/multicore/research/download/HowToGuide-POSIX.pdf